# Run istioctl in Spinnaker pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, istio, spinnaker

Currently we deploy the custom **istio ingress gateways(g/w)** through **helm** using **Spinnaker** pipeline.(One time activity for every k8s namespace)

**istio 1.6** is deprecating the **helm** way of creation of custom user g/w. Instead is asks to deploy it using **istioctl** command.

Since Spinnaker supports only **Helm2** or **Helm3** as rendering engine.

My specific ask is how can I now deploy the custom istio user g/w through helm pipeline using **istioctl** command?

Comment: Maybe you could try to install istio operator with helm as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/#prerequisites) and then install istio with operator as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/#install)?

Comment: My requirement is to just deploy custom istio user g/w not the istio itself

Comment: Then you could create istio operator yaml with your custom gateway, there is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865633/11977760) where they changed default istio ingress gateway values with it.

Comment: Yes that what I am doing now. I wanted to know whether it could be done directly in a Spinnaker stage with istioctl. Looks like it is not possible hence I created a wrapper Docker image which does everything and I am executing this docker image from Spinnaker stage

Comment: Hi @SouvikSarkhel Do you think we can add a 'script' stage to run 'istioctl manifest generate -f ' to obtain the manifest and then deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't get much response. Let me answer it myself.
Here's what I did:

- I took a bitnami kubectl docker base image
- Bundled on of the istio releases say 1.5.8 https://github.com/istio/istio/releases/download/1.5.8/istio-1.5.8-linux.tar.gz
- Get the default manifest using **istioctl manifest generate**
- Modify it accordingly to define a custom ingress-gateway
- Run the following command in the entrypoint.sh for the Docker image
  **istioctl manifest generate -f manifest.yaml | kubecl apply -f -**
- Create a docker image including all the steps
- In Spinnaker pipeline create a stage which deploys based on K8s file.
  In the file define a Job and run the docker image created.

In this way once the job starts running it creates a K8s pod which internally creates the custom user istio ingress g/w.