# Istio Manifest install 1.9

Tags: kubernetes, installation, istio

```
    apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
    kind: IstioOperator
    metadata:
      namespace: istio-system
      name: istio
    spec:
      profile: default
      values:
        gateways:
          istio-ingressgateway:
            #sds:
              enabled: true            
      components:
        base:
          enabled: true                
        ingressGateways:
          - name: istio-ingressgateway
            enabled: true
            namespace: test-ingress
            k8s:
              overlays:
                - apiVersion: v1
                  kind: Gateway
                  name: micro-ingress
                  patches:
                   - path: spec.servers
                     value:
                      - port:
                          number: 80
                          name: http
                          protocol: HTTP
                        hosts:
                        - "*" #host should be specify in VirtualService
                        tls:
                          httpsRedirect: true
                      - port:
                          number: 443
                          name: https
                          protocol: HTTPS
                        hosts:
                        - "*"
                        tls:
                          mode: SIMPLE
                          credentialName: secret
                          privateKey: sds
                          serverCertificate: sds
              serviceAnnotations:
                service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
              service:
                ports:
                - name: status-port
                  port: 15020
                  targetPort: 15020
                - name: http2
                  port: 80
                  targetPort: 8080
                - name: https
                  port: 443
                  targetPort: 8443
                loadBalancerIP: xx.xx.xx.xxx
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 2000m
                  memory: 1024Mi
                requests:
                  cpu: 100m
                  memory: 128Mi
```

> `istioctl manifest apply -f .\manifest.yml`

```
This will install the Istio 1.9.0 default profile with ["Istio core" "Istiod" "Ingress gateways"] components into the cluster.
```

> `Proceed? (y/N) y`

```
Error: failed to install manifests: errors occurred during operation: overlay for Gateway:micro-ingress does not match any object in output 
manifest. Available objects are:
HorizontalPodAutoscaler:test-ingress:istio-ingressgateway
Deployment:test-ingress:istio-ingressgateway
PodDisruptionBudget:test-ingress:istio-ingressgateway
Role:test-ingress:istio-ingressgateway-sds
RoleBinding:test-ingress:istio-ingressgateway-sds
Service:test-ingress:istio-ingressgateway
ServiceAccount:test-ingress:istio-ingressgateway-service-account
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you want to achieve? You want to change the default `istio-ingressgateway` values? If yes then you might refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865633/11977760).

Comment: we are deploying on new cluster using above manifest file, it worked for 1.5, now we are deploying 1.9 on fresh new cluster